# Class "SocialWall/Controller/HomeController" does not exist

Tags: php, namespaces, symfony, silex

I have this error on my web app :

```
InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver.php line 160: Class "SocialWall/Controller/HomeController" does not exist.

    in ControllerResolver.php line 160
    at ControllerResolver->createController('SocialWall/Controller/HomeController::indexAction') in ControllerResolver.php line 76
    at ControllerResolver->getController(object(Request)) in HttpKernel.php line 136
    at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 68
    at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in Application.php line 496
    at Application->handle(object(Request)) in Application.php line 477
    at Application->run() in index.php line 16
```

I use Silex ~2.0 and I have just refactoring my controllers list like that :

My tree :

- root/app/app.php
- root/app/routes.php
- root/src/Controller/HomeController.php
- root/web/index.php

index.php :

```
<?php
/** Front controller */

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

require __DIR__.'/../app/config/dev.php';
require __DIR__.'/../app/app.php';
require __DIR__.'/../app/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

routes.php

```
    <?php

    // Home page
    $app->get('/', "SocialWall/Controller/HomeController::indexAction")->bind('home');

    // Detailed info about an article
    $app->match('/article/{id}', "SocialWall/Controller/HomeController::articleAction")->bind('article');

    // Login form
    $app->get('/login', "SocialWall/Controller/HomeController::loginAction")->bind('login');   
//...
```

HomeController.php

```
    <?php

    namespace SocialWall\Controller;

    use Silex\Application;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use SocialWall\Domain\Comment;
    use SocialWall\Form\Type\CommentType;

    class HomeController {

        /**
         * Home page controller.
         *
         * @param Application $app Silex application
         */
        public function indexAction(Application $app) {
            $articles = $app['dao.article']->findAll();
            return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));
        }
//...
```

my composer.json :

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "2.0.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*",
        "twig/twig": "1.24.*",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.1",
        "symfony/security": "^3.1",
        "symfony/form": "^3.1",
        "symfony/config": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "^3.1",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
        "symfony/validator": "^3.1",
        "sorien/silex-pimple-dumper": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.5",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^3.1",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^3.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.21"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"SocialWall\\": "src"}
    }
}
```

What's wrong ?

[EDIT]
OK I fix it.. in route.php on function's second argument I have replace all the '/' by '\'.
Initialy phpStorm underline me all the '\' in red, so I replaced '\' by '/'.. Thanks phpStorm ...

Comment: can you post your composer.json files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My logs (if it can help)

```
[2016-09-15 10:03:12] SocialWall.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"home","route_parameters":{"_controller":"SocialWall/Controller/HomeController::indexAction","_route":"home"},"request_uri":"http://socialwall/","method":"GET"} []
[2016-09-15 10:03:12] SocialWall.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: Class "SocialWall/Controller/HomeController" does not exist. (uncaught exception) at /opt/lampp/htdocs/SocialWall/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php line 160 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Class \"SocialWall/Controller/HomeController\" does not exist. at /opt/lampp/htdocs/SocialWall/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:160)"} []
[2016-09-15 10:03:12] SocialWall.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"b65c04","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://socialwall/_profiler/wdt/b65c04","method":"GET"} []
```

[EDIT] OK I fix it.. in route.php on function's second argument I have replace all the '/' by '\'
Initialy phpStorm underline me the '\' in red, so I replaced '\' by '/'.. Thanks phpStorm ...

Answer (score 0):

you specified the wrong namespace:

```
namespace Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use SocialWall\Domain\Comment;
use SocialWall\Form\Type\CommentType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    ...
```

You also need to exend Controller.

**EDIT #2**
Did you change your routes too:

```
$app->get('/', "Controller/HomeController::indexAction")->bind('home');

// Detailed info about an article
$app->match('/article/{id}', "Controller/HomeController::articleAction")->bind('article');

// Login form
$app->get('/login', "Controller/HomeController::loginAction")->bind('login');   
//...
```

Comment: See my EDIT #2. Also, have you tried the debug URL using `http://host/app_dev.php/route`, this provides a bit more debugging information that might help.

Comment: Same error here but with : Class "Controller/HomeController" does not exist.